# pandas select dataframe rows according to pair condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe like following:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'contract':[11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13], 
    'num_date':[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    'val': [100, 110, 120, 50, 150, 95, 105, 115, 125]
})
```

Pairs (contracts, num_date) are unique

Also I have the list of tuples:

```py
filt = [(11, 1),
        (11, 1),
        (12, 3),
        (12, 2),
        (13, 3),
        (13, 1)]
```

Each tuple in list is a pair (contract, num_date) for dataframe above.

I need choose rows from dataframe according to this list as a condition, and if the tuple is repeated several times then the row corresponding to it also must be repeated the same number of times.

For example for dataframe and list of tuples above solution is

| contract | num_date | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 | 100 |
| 11 | 1 | 100 |
| 12 | 2 | 150 |
| 13 | 3 | 115 |
| 13 | 1 | 95 |

Will be better if the solution will be *time-efficient*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert the tuples into a dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(filt)
df2.columns = ['contract', 'num_date']
```

Then merge between the two and drop nulls:

```
df2 = df2.merge(right=df, on = ['contract', 'num_date'], how='left')
df2.dropna(subset=['val'], inplace=True)
```